# Ionic4-angular chatbot and dialogflow v2

Tags: angular, sdk, ionic4, dialogflow-es

How can I connect ionic dialogflow v2 ?Im trying to develop a chatbot and Im not sure how to make this connection and then see the results on localhost.Do I need to use firebase for this? I have downloaded the json file from dialogflow but at the moment im reall confused about how to use it. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone that maybe face this in the future:
1)create a node js server and make post requests from ionic to this server.
2)on the post request function in your node js server complete also the runsample function of this example https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow
3)the returned response in ionic from the server is the intent!